# Firebase with Node, "browser-targeted Firebase bundle"

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-storage

I got the npm "firebase" package for Node, made a firebaseConfig.js file and then added this:

```
const firebase = require("firebase/app");
console.log(firebase);

const firebaseConfig = {
 ...
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

At first, I got an error saying "initializeApp isn't a function", which I really didn't get, after seeing the contents of `firebase`, I changed the last line to

`firebase.default.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`

Which works, but now I'm getting this warning on the console;

```
      Warning: This is a browser-targeted Firebase bundle but it appears it is being
      run in a Node environment.  If running in a Node environment, make sure you
      are using the bundle specified by the "main" field in package.json.
```

I really don't get what I should do here, I could really use some guidance so thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hi @Gabriel, did you find a solution meanwhile?

Answer (score -1):

When you use firebase in server-side, you should use firebase-admin.

> To set up administrative access from privileged environments (such as servers) set up the Firebase Admin SDK instead.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup